# How to read an array from XML-RPC

Tags: c++, xml-rpc

```
xmlrpc_c::clientSimple myClient;
xmlrpc_c::value Result

...

myClient.call(serverUrl, "getattr", "s", &result, pName);
```

If the result is an array, how do I read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it....

```
typdef std::vector<xmlrpc_c::value> carray;

...

function(...){

  carray c = xmlrpc_c::value_array(result).cvalue();
  cout << xmlrpc_c::value_int(c[0]);

}

...
```